# getServletContext().getInitParameter("contextName") does not return port number in the url

Tags: java, servlets, port

I'm working with some old jsp apps and we are moving servers and so the urls have changed. The new url's we were given have port numbers in them - http://example.com:8686/theapp

Now this line `getServletContext().getInitParameter("contextName")` returns `example/` instead of `example:8686/`.

Is there a similar function or parameter that I can use so that the port number will be displayed in the url?

Comment: getServletContext().getInitParameter() returns the value that you wrote in the init-param attribute in the web.xml file. Change it to whatever you want, and it will return the new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getServletContext().getInitParameter()` returns the value of a `<context-param>` of the given name which is hard specified in `web.xml`. This is not a dynamic value. You'd basically need to edit the `<context-param>` in question in order to provide the "right" value.

To dynamically get the port number of the current HTTP servlet request, you need to use [`HttpServletRequest#getServerPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerPort%28%29) or [`HttpServletRequest#getLocalPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort%28%29) instead, depending on which port number exactly you'd like to obtain: the one as specified in `Host` header, or the one which the server is actually using.

Please note that you'd normally use [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) to obtain the context name.

Comment: I figured this out right after writing it too. I looked in the web.xml file. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you need port alone:

```
request.getLocalPort() or request.getServerPort()
```

If you need port along with IP and context name:

```
request.getContextPath() or request.getServletPath() or request.getLocalAddr()
```

for more information refer the below links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html
http://www.kodejava.org/examples/211.html